# Convolution of independent standard normal random variables

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

> Let $X$ and $Y$ be two independent random variables, each with the standard
>   normal density. Compute $f_{X+Y} (a)$.

The solution uses a convolution of the form

$$f_{X+Y}(a)= {1\over 2\pi} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}
e^{-{(a-y)^2}\over2}e^{-{y^2}\over2} \ dy$$

I am wondering why the bounds are $\infty$ and not $a$ and $0$ such as I found in another problem- *Let $X$ and $Y$ be two independent exponential random variables with common
parameter $λ$. Compute $f_{X+Y} (a)$*, where the solution uses $f_{X+Y}(a)= \int_{0}^{a}
λe^{-λ(a-y)}λe^{-λy}\ dy$

Why are the bounds $\infty$ when the sum of $X$ and $Y$ is no more than $a$? Is this something special about the standard normal variable?

Comment: $X+Y=a\Rightarrow a-Y=X$. X is normally distributed and goes from $-\infty$ to $\infty$. Consequently $a-Y$ has the same limits. The exponential variable is $0$ for $X<0$. Do you see the difference?

Comment: Why is the exponential variable $0$ for $X<0$?

Comment: That is the definition of the [exponential variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution#Probability_density_function).

Comment: Ok, I get that. What about the upper bound of $\infty$? Why does that not work for the exponential variable?

Comment: If $a-y>0$  then $y<a$

Comment: Ok, makes sense now. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: You´re welcome.